# DynamoDB tables without RANGE value

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, serverless

Would there be any problem if I create my table without a RANGE value (ie, HASH value only)? I've heard that DynamoDB tables store entries in partitions, and these partitions are determined using the HASH key. If I use only HASH key on my table, would it cause too many partitions? Also, would it increase the time to seek data in my table using queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no drawback, the hash key decides the partition the data will live on and the partitions are designed to handle up to 3k RCU and 1k WCU or up to 10GB of data.
Performance "guarantees" are based on them delivering that, so it shouldn't matter.

Having unique partition keys may actually help you with scaling later down the line as chances are that requests can be spread out more evenly, since there is no query operation that works on multiple items in an item collection.

Comment: Thank you Maurice! Stay safe!

Comment: 1/ It is 3k Reads, 1k writes, OR a linear mix of the two, per partition. For example, you could have 500 writes and 1500 reads per partition as a write is worth 3 IOPS and a read is worth 1 IOPS and a partition support 3000 IOPS. 2/ There are no performance guarantees with DynamoDB, but there is an uptime SLA.

Answer (score 2):

> would it cause too many partitions?

There's no such thing in Dynamo DB.

> would it increase the time to seek data in my table using queries

You can't Query() a DDB table unless it has a range key.  With a only a hash key you can only use GetItem().  Scan() is also allowed, but you really shouldn't be using that regularly.

You'd have to add a Global Secondary Index (GSI) with a has & range key in order to Query() your data.

Comment: "There's no such thing in Dynamo DB." - Having too many partitions can be inconvenient if you suddenly decide to significantly downsize a large table, because AFAIK partitions can't be merged (meaning the # of partitions can only grow). In that case capacity units would be distributed evenly across a large number of partitions, which may be a disadvantage in bursty situations (although adaptive capacity somewhat mitigates this).

Comment: Just to be pedantic, you can do a query, but it is only going to bring back one item as without a sort (range) key, the partition key must be unique. So a query is the same as doing a GetItem.